# How to open(), read() and write() contents of file from input?

Tags: c

I need to read contents from a file whose name is passed when executing the program, and I have no idea how to do it. I can only use the functions `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`. How can I do it in an easy way that I can understand?

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    ssize_t i;
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    char* buf;
    ssize_t nr_bytes;
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if (fd == -1) {
        write(1,"Error", 5);
        return 0;
    }

    nr_bytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (nr_bytes == 0) {
        write(1, "Empty", 5);
    }

    buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * nr_bytes);

    while ((i = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
       write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, i);
    }
    
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you delete lines 13-18, change `buf` to `buffer` and `#include` the correct header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do it in an easy way that I can understand?

This part of the question makes writing an answer a bit tricky. All I can do is show you how it is done usually - using the depicted set of functions. And leave the second part (whether you can understand it) to your own judgement.

You need no temporary buffer.
Instead:

1. Open the file with `open()`.
2. Get the file size with `fstat()`.
3. Allocate a big enough buffer with `malloc()`.
4. read the data into the buffer with `read()`.
5. close the file with `close()`.
6. Live happily ever after with the contents of the buffer.
7. When you don't need the buffer anylonger, don't forget to `free()` it.

Any other stuff you see in the code below are checks to make sure we do nothing evil in case something goes wrong.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool read_file(const char* file_path, void** target, size_t* target_size) {
  if (NULL == target)
    return false;
  if (NULL == target_size) {
    return false;
  }
  int fd = open( file_path, O_RDONLY);
  if (-1 == fd)
    return false;
  struct stat st;
  fstat(fd, &st);
  *target = malloc(st.st_size);
  if (NULL == *target) {
    close(fd);
    return false;
  }
  size_t nread = read(fd, *target, st.st_size);
  close(fd);
  if (nread != st.st_size) {
    free(*target);
    *target = NULL;
    return false;
  }
  *target_size = st.st_size;
  return true;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    void* content = NULL;
    size_t content_size = 0;
    if (read_file(argv[1], &content, &content_size)) {
      printf("read_file() succeeded and read %zu bytes of data from %s.\n",
         content_size, argv[1]);
      free(content);
      content = NULL;
    } else {
      printf("read_file() failed for file %s.\n", argv[1]);
    }
  } else {
    printf("we expect the path to the file in the applications first command line argument!");
  }
}
```